# NullPointerException at adding in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database

I'm trying to add a row in my database, at the table employee.
But i get an exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ConnectionBD.EmployeeBD.add(EmployeeBD.java:56)`
```

This is my source code (EmployeeBD Class):

```
public void add() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
56      Employee a = ep.ReadEmployee();
57      if (a!=null) {
58          Connection conn = null; 
        try  { 
            Class.forName(BDConnect.DRIVER);
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(BDConnect.BD_URL, BDConnect.USUARI, BDConnect.PASSWORD);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE ); 
            if (conn != null) {
                String sql = "SELECT * FROM employee";
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery( sql ); 
                rs.moveToInsertRow();
                rs.updateString( "nif", a.getNif());
                rs.updateString( "name", a.getName());
                rs.updateDouble( "salary",a.getSalary());
                System.out.println("Added Suscefully");
                rs.insertRow();
                rs.moveToCurrentRow();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Can't get DB");
            }
        } catch (SQLException ioe) { 
            System.out.println(ioe); 
        } catch(ClassNotFoundException ex) { 
            System.out.println(ex); 
        }
    }
}
```

And the ReadEmployee() Method:

```
public Employee ReadEmployee() {
    String nif = null;
    String name = null;
    Double salary = null;
    int depId = 0;

    nif = jTextField1.getText();
    name = jTextField2.getText();
    salary = Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
    Employee  emp = new Employee(nif, name, salary, 1);

    if (name.equals("") || nif.equals("") || salary != null) {
        return emp;
    } else {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fill all TextFields", "Article warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Why It throws the exception? 
I don't know how to do it correcty!

Comment: please write the line number in the source code so that we can figure out at which line the exception is thrown.. Thanks

Comment: Please some more information to better understand ...

Comment: you should check `conn != null` **before** you call `createStatement` on it

Comment: `if (name.equals("") || nif.equals("") || salary != null) {` This isn't working as check for empty values. You want to return emp if all fields are filled, but you are returning emp if name or nif are empty and salary must be different than null. To check it correctly you must use `if (!name.equals("") && !nif.equals("") && salary != null) {return emp;}` and for the `else` condition, if you want to throw the message when only a single field it's not filled up use `else if (name.equals("") || nif.equals("") || salary == null) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (name.equals("") || nif.equals("") || salary != null) {
    ...
}
```

This isn't working as spected check for empty values. You want to return `emp` if all fields are filled, but you are returning `emp` if name or nif are empty, or salary is not null. To check it correctly you must use:

```
if (!name.equals("") && !nif.equals("") && salary != null) {
    return emp;
}
```

And for the `else` condition, if you want to throw the message when a single field it's not filled up use:

```
else if (name.equals("") || nif.equals("") || salary == null) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fill all TextFields", "Article warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return null;
}
```

**UPDATE**

I must recommend you that if it's not **STRICTLY NECESSARY, NEVER** initialize variables. Sometimes, null pointers can drive you crazy and if you are handling `SQLException` and `ClassNotFoundException` using:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ...
} catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
    ...
}
```

You don't have to add `throws` clause to your methods.

Answer (score 0):

jTextField1.getText() - please add null check for jTextField1.. if its null .getText() can throw Null pointer exception

Comment: This is not the problem in this specific case

Answer (score 0):

Okay now that you've put in line numbers it is clear that `ep` is `null`:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ConnectionBD.EmployeeBD.add(EmployeeBD.java:56)`
```

This is my source code (EmployeeBD Class):

```
56  Employee a = ep.ReadEmployee();
```

Comment: Yeah, I also thought that, but if I initialize variables with values ​​also happens

Comment: please show us the code where you init `ep` and call the above method. It might also be possible that the line numbers are incorrect due to comment lines. Did you try to debug yet?

Answer (score 0):

Consider working on the if-else block of ReadEmployee:

```
if (name.equals("") || nif.equals("") || salary != null) {
    return emp;
} else {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Fill all TextFields", "Article warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return null;
}
```

The if condition states that : if name is empty or nif is empty or salary is not null, then return emp.

But as per else block looks like if condition should be:

```
if (! name.equals("") && ! nif.equals("") && salary != null)
```